# xCode can't connect to localhost after xcode 6.1 update

Tags: php, ios, xcode, swift

My app makes use of a PHP backend API (in Laravel) (and another app uses standard PHP, not a framework).

I had xCode 6.0 and my apps connected to the server just fine, now I upgraded to 6.1, and no app I have will connect to the server. The error it gives is:

```
The requested URL was not found on the server.
```

This is very frustrating.

The following is the URL:

```
var URL: String = "http://localhost/laravel/myProject/public/"
```

and in the browser:

[image: in the browser]

So as you can see, it works just fine in the browser.

Here is the connection script:

```
var post:NSString = "username=\(GlobalVars.sharedInstance.getUsername())&&lat=\(lat)&&long=\(lng)"        
var url:NSURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "\(GlobalVars.sharedInstance.getURL())login")!
var postData:NSData = post.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to communicate with a http server you should use `NSURL(string:)` instead of `NSURL(fileURLWithPath:)`. Currently you just create a file URL with a strange name.

e.g.:

```
var url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "\(GlobalVars.sharedInstance.getURL())login")!
```

---

If something doesn't work as expected you should start by inspect the variables that are involved. You probably would have caught the issue, since the URL would be something like `file://http:/localhost`

Comment: Perfect! xCode suggested the `fileURLWithPath` and I am new so I thought that was the best bet. Thanks!